# Display the imported text generated from a Tk button function in a Tk Text

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

i'm just new to programming in python. 
I'd like to create a sample project wherein I import a text file in a Button click command and display it in an Text widget. The Button function is in a different class called ButtonAction, and the widget is created in another class called Window. The problem is I don't have an idea how to get the existing Text widget so i can append the imported data.

I removed some formatting codes.

Code:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        textarea = Text(self)
        textarea.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4,
                    padx=10, pady=10, sticky=E + W + S + N)

        imprtbutton = Button(self, text="Import XML", command=ButtonAction().import_onclick)
        imprtbutton.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, sticky=S)


class ButtonAction:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_onclick(self):
        file = askopenfile(mode='r')
        if file is not None:
            content = file.read()
            print(content) #just so i can see if i successfully imported my txt file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500+300+200")
    root.title("Test Project")
    gui = Window()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.

When I started your script, I was not able to see the "Import XML" button at all. I needed to resize the window first. That is the reason, why I played around with the `.pack` and `.grid` calls in your code.

To solve your problem, I added the argument `callback` to your `import_onclick` method. This provides a means for the `ButtonAction` class to return the data back to the `Window` class. Here the new method `update_text` is responsible for filling the content of `textarea`.

Because we now need an additional argument for `import_onclick`, I wrapped the former `ButtonAction().import_onclick` argument into a lambda:

```
lambda: ButtonAction().import_onclick(self.update_text)
```

The resulting code works fine for me:

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import *


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textarea = Text(self)

        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.textarea.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        import_button = Button(self,
                               text="Import XML",
                               command=lambda: ButtonAction().import_onclick(self.update_text)
                               )
        import_button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

    def update_text(self, text):
        self.textarea.delete(1.0, END)
        self.textarea.insert(END, text)


class ButtonAction:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_onclick(self, callback):
        file = askopenfile(mode='r')
        if file is not None:
            content = file.read()
            # just so i can see if i successfully imported my txt file
            print(f"read {len(content)} lines")
            callback(content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test Project")
    gui = Window()
    root.mainloop()
```